# If $\frac{a}{b}$ is fully reduced, then $a$ is odd or $b$ is odd.

Tags: solution-verification

Is the following contrapositive proof correct?

**Proposition**: If $\frac{a}{b}$ is fully reduced, then $a$ is odd or $b$ is odd.

**Proof**: Suppose that $a$ is even and $b$ is even, then $\exists k,\ell \in \mathbb{Z},a = 2k,b=2\ell$, and therefore
$$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{2k}{2\ell}
$$
is not fully reduced.

Comment: ... because one could cancel the common factor $2$ to get $\frac{k}{l}$.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy good catch.

Comment: Outside of those minor flaws, this is exactly correct. Very good

Comment: Yep, that's it.  You can put it in other words but that's it.